# Importing Module without routes

Tags: angular

I have a situation where our main app lazily loads other modules:

```
//main NgModule
RouterModule.forRoot(
[
  {path:'profile', loadChildren:'path/to/profile.module#ProfileModule}, 
  {path:'classroom', loadChildren:'path/to/classroom.module#ClassroomModule},
  {path:'tests', loadChildren:'path/to/test.module#TestsModule}
])
```

Now the profile module has a few components in it that are necessary for the Classroom module.

```
//Profile NgModule
RouterModule.forChild(
[
  {path:'', component:ProfileComponent, 
])

//Classroom NgModule
imports: [
  ProfileModule,
  RouterModule.forChild(
  [
    {path:'', component:ClassroomComponent} //this requires a component in ProfileModule
  ])
]
```

This compiles nicely but when I try to navigate to '/classroom' all I get is the ProfileComponent

I suppose this is because the ProfileModules route configuration is being combined with the ClassroomModule route configuration. Is there a way I could prevent this from happening? I'd prefer not having to remove all of the shared components from ProfileModule and putting them into a new shared module if possible.

Comment: I fixed my problem by removing shared code to a shared module as @Markus has suggested, however, it's not an answer to my question.

Comment: This is quite an annoying problem, have you raised an issue on the official angular repo? they probably didn't think about this use case

Answer (score 26):

The best way I found to do this was to create a Module which does all the declarations of the original module but without importing the routing.

```
<Module Name>WithoutRouting.ts
```

I then create anther module

```
<Module Name>.ts
```

Where I import the routing and the `<Module Name>WithoutRouting.ts` module.

Then when I want to use the module with routing, for example when lazy loaded I use `<Module Name>.ts` and if I want to import the Module directly I use `<Module Name>WithoutRouting.ts`.

Comment: simple and steady

Comment: where do you declare components? you know you can declare them only once

Comment: @Ayyash you declare them in `ModuleWithoutRouting`, and if you want to use them in `ModuleWithRouting` then add them to the `exports: []` list of `ModuleWithoutRouting`

Comment: one some detail with this solution: don't forget to `import` the `RouterModule` in the `ModuleWithoutRouting` otherwise you won't be able to use `routerLink` or other things like that

Comment: @Guillaume i ended up doing just that, re-importing the modulewithoutrouting into the routed module to reuse its components..

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar issue. All I found is that if you put a module already combined with a RouterModule before the current module's routing module, it will just use the imported module's routing if any path matches the pattern. So make sure your routing module is imported at the very beginning, just after CommonModule maybe, it'll be safer.

Comment: I tried both ways and it always picks up the routes from the imported module, very annoying

Comment: @Guillaume Have you found a solution?

Comment: @laprof I always end up having 2 modules per feature so one is for routing the other one is for exporting

Answer (score 1):

try to invert the position of the imports

```
 //Classroom NgModule
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(
      [
        {path:'', component:ClassroomComponent} 
      ],
      ProfileModule
)
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to make a difference